# .htaccess how to remove file extensions and index files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to achieve a few things through .htaccess ,but keep running into issues.  Before you tell me I need to research better and there's already a solution on this or a different forum, please know I've already done that.  I always try and figure out things on my own before coming here, but this one is truly stumping me.  Everything I've tried has only partially worked.  Any help or education here would be truly appreciated.

My site has the following simple structure:

```
(root)
 |   index.html
 |   .htaccess
 |
 |___portal-folder
      |     index.php
      |     home.php
      |
      |_____admin-folder
             |     index.php
```

I'm looking to achieve the following:

1. When a user navigates to any base directory, for instance `site.com` or `site.com/portal-folder/` they don't see the index file name `index.html` or `index.php` in their browser.
2. Same holds true if the user navigates to the full URL `site.com/index.html` or `site.com/portal-folder/index.php`  I would like the user to see `site.com` or `site.com/portal-folder/` respectively in their browser.
3. Strip the file extension off all files in the browser. So for instance navigating to `site.com/portal-folder/home.php` would show as `site.com/portal-folder/home` in the browser

The following code I'm using kind of works, but I'm getting strange behavior.  For instance:

- navigating to `site.com/portal-folder/index` doesn't remove the index file name and show up as `site.com/portal-folder/index` instead of `site.com/portal-folder/` in the browser
- navigating to `site.com/portal-folder/` doesn't remove the index file name and shows up as `site.com/portal-folder/index.php` in the browser.
- navigating to `site.com/portal-folder/index.php` takes the user back to the root `site.com`
- navigating to `site.com/portal-folder/home` works correctly, but navigating to `site.com/portal-folder/home.php` doesn't strip the .php extension off.
- navigating to `site.com` works correctly, but navigating to `site.com/index.html` doesn't remove the index file name.

  ```
  RewriteEngine On

  DirectoryIndex index.html  index.php

  # remove trailing slash
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

  # To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
  ```

**Server Information: Apache Version    2.4.46**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file and optionally remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))(?:\.php|\.html)?[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works great now!  One thing though, but it not a big deal.  I noticed if a user navigates to `site.com/index` it does not switch to `site.com` it does work if they navigate to `site.com/index.html` by switching to `site.com`

Comment: Please check my latest edited rule. It takes care of `/index` also

Comment: Thanks @anubhava but the update you posted did not work for me.  It ended up erroring out on every page I tried to visit.  I ended up moving forward with your original version.

Comment: That is strange because I had tested it before posting.